# Programs halts when trying to create a new Socket with existing ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

So I am running a piece of code that is supposed to create a Socket a ServerSocket, when I run my code it meets a stand still at line 14 but doesn't throw any exception. What have I missed?

```
public class Syncronizer {

    InputStream instr = null;
    PrintStream prnstr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    ServerSocket TCPServerSocket;

    public Syncronizer() {
        try {
            instr = System.in;
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instr));
            TCPServerSocket = new ServerSocket(7007);
            Socket clientSocket = TCPServerSocket.accept();
            in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Just to spare you the counting it is this line that halts my program:

```
Socket clientSocket = TCPServerSocket.accept();
```

EDIT: With halt I mean that my program still runs but doesn't go beyond this point in the code just like a infinite loop.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Have you opened a connection to the server?

Comment: I want this client to be a pipe/echo. So for now I want to just open a stream and then later handle the source and sink part.

Comment: A stream to _what_? A connection has two endpoints.

Comment: This program must be both a sink and a source and I want my sources to output the data and my sinks to receive them. I need multiple threads of this program which is why I chose to work with TCP sockets in the first place.

Comment: Forget about sink and source for a moment. You have a **server** socket. Where's the **client**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accept()` is expected to block until a connection comes in on the port the socket the code calls `accept()` for is listening on.

You might like to RTFM here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

Comment: Oh, bloody right you right! Thank you, I have completely forgotten/overlooked that.